# ruby - how to pad "groups of 5 characters" with undersores  in last group?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, string-substitution

I want my string in groups of 5 characters, .e.g.

```
thisisastring => ["thisi", "satri", "ng"]
```

but I also want the last group to be padded with __'s, e.g.

```
thisisastring => ["thisi", "satri", "ng___"]
```

I have got as far as the string splitting:

```
"thisisastring".scan /.{5}/)

["thisi", "satri", "ng"]
```

but not too sure how to do the padding for that last group to make it "ng___"

although starting to think that combinations of dividend (`div()`), modulus (`%`) and `.ljust` might do it.

Maybe number of padding characters would be: `(length % 5) * "_"` (if you can multiply that)  ?

Perhaps something that uses:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :023 > (len % 5).to_i.times { print '_' }
___ => 3
```

Comment: Not a Ruby expert, but why not just check the last element in the array for its length. Append 5-length '_'s to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the adjustment is only required on the last element, it is more effective to do the adjustment before splitting rather than itterating over the elements to do adjustment.

```
("thisisastring"+"_"*("thisisastring".length % 5)).scan(/.{5}/)
```

Answer (score 6):

Not even *close* to efficient, but if you wanted t to one-line it, something like this should work:

```
"thisisastring".scan(/.{1,5}/).collect {|x| x.ljust(5,"_")}
```

Comment: I like it.  When you say not close to efficient it would probably be better than using activesupport, no?

Comment: I can do timing runs but wanted opinion too

Comment: it runs `ljust` on every item in the enumeration, when really the last item is the only one that is ever less than 5 characters long.